Can't import env to anaconda navigator
I have a .txt file. I tried to upload / import this file to anaconda environment but I get the following error:

CondaEnvException : pip failed

This is the contents of that .txt file:
jupyter==1.0.0
lxml==4.5.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.2
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.1
openpyxl==3.0.4
pandas==1.1.2
Pillow==7.2.0
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18

I tried to import the file to anaconda navigator, and setup a new environment
